# Given a Banach or Hilbert space $X$, when can the spaces $\mathcal{L}_p(X)$ be constructed?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

The spaces $\mathcal{L}_p(\mathbb{R})$ consist of the real functions $f$ for which 
$$
\int_0^\infty |f(x)|^pdx < +\infty.
$$
Similarly $\mathcal{L}_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ can be naturally interpreted as the space with elements $[f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n]^{tr}$ such that each $f_k$ is a function of the reals and
$$
\int_0^\infty \left(\sum_{k=1}^n|f_k(x)|^2\right)^{p/2}dx < +\infty.
$$
Is there a general proceedure for assigning such $\mathcal{L}_p$-spaces to  functions of a general Banach / Hilbert / separable Hilbert space $X$?

Comment: Well in general, for **any** set $X$, if $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$ algebra of subsets of $X$ and $\mu$ is a measure on $(X, \mathcal{F})$, we define $L^p(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)=\{f: X \to \mathbb{C} : \int_X |f|^p d\mu < \infty \}$. For $p \in [1, \infty)$, the space $L^p(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ modulo the functions that are 0 almost everywhere w.t.r. to $\mu$, is a normed vector space with $\|[f]\|_p=( \int_X |f|^p d\mu )^{1/p}$ that turns out to be a Banach space.

Comment: You can use any norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ since they are all equivalent you will end up with the same  space.

Comment: Read, for example, Rudin-Fuctional Analysis.

Comment: You mean functions *into* a Banach space, right? Your notation $L_p(X)$ may have confused some of the commenters because when there is only one argument, it typically refers to the domain of the functions. I believe Lebesgue integrals with values in a Banach space are treated in Lang's *Real and Functional Analysis*. I don't think they're really covered in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, except for a brief mention of a "weak" integral with values in an EVT. As long as $X^*$ separates points on $X$, which is the case in a Banach space, you can give a weak definition as follows. Define

Comment: $\int f = v$ to mean that $\int \phi \circ f = \phi(v)$ for every continuous linear functional $\phi$. A "strong" definition of the integral of $f$ will generally agree with this one when it exists, but it will exist for fewer functions $f$. More of the usual properties of Lebesgue integrals will be valid with a "strong" definition, like the one in Lang.

Comment: Sorry, by "EVT" I meant "TVS" - topological vector space.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is called the [Bochner space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space) and it can be constructed for every Banach space $X$ and every $p\in [1,\infty]$.

Much of the theory of $L^p$ spaces carries over. A notable subtlety is that it's not true in general that the dual of $L^p(X)$, $1\le p<\infty$, is $L^q(X^*)$ where $1/p+1/q=1$ and $X^*$ is the dual space of $X$.   However, this relation holds when $X$ has the [Radon–Nikodym property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_property).

Reference: [Martingales in Banach Spaces](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/abstract-analysis/martingales-banach-spaces?format=HB&isbn=9781107137240#rgJO0guFHTsLd7Tk.97) by G. Pisier.